# Clone ObservableCollection

Tags: c#

I have class with `ObservableCollection` and other properties.
So it looks a little bit like this:

```
public class A
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   ...
   public object AValue {get; set;}
}
```

I would like clone object of this class. `AValue` property can be `ObservableCollection` or another object. When `AValue` is of type ObservableCollection and I trying to add some object to it it's seems that clone have the same object that orginal. If I use my clone method only to `AValue` Property, not to object of class `A` it works. To clone objects I tried to use:

```
 private object Clone(object obj)
    {
        var t = obj.GetType();

        if (obj == null)
            return null;

        if (t.IsValueType || t == typeof(string))
        {
            return obj;
        }
        else if (t.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (obj is IList)
            {
                var c= typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
                var cType = type.GetGenericArguments().First();
                var gType = c.MakeGenericType(cType);
                var newC = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(gType);

                foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj)
                    newC.Add(item);

                return newC;
            }
        }
        else if (t.IsClass)
        {
            object objV = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                object fieldV = field.GetValue(obj);
                if (fieldValue == null)
                    continue;
                field.SetValue(objV, Clone(fieldV));
            }
            return obj;
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type");
    }
}
```

**Edit**
thanks for answer.
I added your code @Sefe but it still doesn't works. I know that other types doesn't clone but I would like to  do it with lists first. I don't known where is mistake. I get the A class object then I clone object and send A class object to dialogbox. I change collection and properties from clone and orginal are the same. 
It's enought to add IClonable interface to generic type of list

```
 ObservableCollection<B> = new  ObservableCollection<B>();

public class B: Base, ICloneable
{
  ...
  public object Clone()
  {
    return this.MemberwiseClone();
  }
```

}

Is it important that generic type can inherit from another class?

Comment: You have a possible bug in your code. What about generic types that are not lists? They will not be cloned.

Comment: @Sefe  I stumbled over that too but in that case an exception is thrown which is fine (could be a NotImplementedException perhaps, but still).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are cloning the collection, but you are not cloning its items. To create a deep clone of the collection, you need to also clone the items (if possible):

```
foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj) {
    ICloneable cloneable = item as ICloneable;
    if (cloneable != null) {
        newC.Add(cloneable.Clone());
    }
    else {
        newC.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Using the `ICloneable` interface is the built-in way in the .NET framework and you can expect framweork methods to recognize it where necessary. So this would be the preferred way. If you want to reuse your own existing `Clone` method instead, you can call it recursively:

```
foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj) {
    newC.Add(Clone(item));
}
```

**UPDATE (To adress the question's edit):**

When you use `MemberwiseClone`, *all* fields and events will be transferred to the clone. `MemberwiseClone` creates a *shallow* copy, so the fields and assigned event handlers are transferred. So if you have fields that contain other reference types, these will be not cloned (even if they are `ICloneable`). Also, event handlers that are assigned to the orginal, will also be assigned to the clone.

Your `ICloneable.Clone` method will have to take care to put the clone in a valid state. Because what is valid differs from case to case, there is no automatic deep cloning in the .NET framework. Invoking `MemberwiseClone` is usually a good start, but you have to then adress contained objects, event handlers etc. to "upgrade" your shallow clone to a deep clone.

Comment: When I needed to deep copy collections frequently I wrote an extension for containers. The signature is `public static TContainer CloneDeep<TContainer, T>( this TContainer r ) 
            where T : ICloneable
            where TContainer: ICollection<T>, new()`. 
The normal generics all have a `new()`, so it works for commonly encountered lists etc. The function trivially iterates through the source container and `Clone()`s the elements, adding them to the cloned container. Note that a Dictionary needs a special treatment which clones keys and values.